# ios how to generate a int random number of float range

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, random

I'm getting a random number float value:

```
float myFloat=120.12123123123;
int tmpInt = floorf(myFloat);
int ran=rand()%tmpInt;
```

But I'm trying to do everything one line:

```
float myFloat=120.12123123123;
int ran=rand()%([[floorf(myFloat)] intValue]);
```

but on this line I'm getting the following error:

> "int ran=rand()%([[floorf(myFloat)] intValue]);" error : "Expeted
>   identifier"

How can I fix this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: `[floorf(myFloat)]` -- that's not legal syntax.  (Yeah, I've done it several times too.  Even if you do it more or less correctly sometimes the editor "helps" you too much.)

Comment: `int ran = rand() % floorf(myFloat);` Please find your space bar located conveniently at the bottom center of your keyboard.  :)

Comment: Nor is `intValue` of course... `int ran = rand() % (int)floorf(myFloat);` will do the job

Comment: Oh, "*expected* identifier." Got it. Wondered WTH "expeted" meant! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` is a primitive type, so you can just cast it. For example,

```
int ran = rand() % (int)floorf(myFloat);
```

The compiler might not even require the `(int)` cast...

You might want to look at this relevant SO question: [What is a Type Cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558837/what-exactly-is-a-type-cast-in-c-c)