# Explicit type casting operator in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, casting

The following code converts the float type  `7.5` to an integer value `7`, the remainder is lost. Here, the typecasting operator is `int`. I know it is valid typecast in C++.

```
int main()
{
        int i;
        float f = 7.5;
        i = (int) f; // Valid in C/C++
}
```

But another way to do the same thing in `C/C++` is to use the **functional notation** preceding the expression to be converted by the type and enclosing the expression between parentheses:

```
i = int (f); // It is worked in C++ but not C
```

So, I have a question, **Is it valid way to typecast in C++?**

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Comment: there's no C/C++ language. It's one of C++ typecast syntaxes so read a book before asking things like this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast http://stackoverflow.com/q/7558837/995714

Comment: @R Sahu Sorry, It is not work in C but In C++, it working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = int (f);
```

is valid in C++ but not in C.

From the C99 Standard, **6.5.4 Cast operators**

> ```
>  cast-expression:
>       unary-expression
>       ( type-name ) cast-expression
> ```

C++ supports the above form of casting as well as function style casting. Function style casting is like calling the constructor of a type to construct on object.

Check out the following block code compiled using C and C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   float f = 10.2;
   int i = int(f);

   printf("i: %d\n", i);
}
```

Non-working C program: http://ideone.com/FfNR5r

Working C++ program: http://ideone.com/bSP7sL

Answer (score 2):

It is in C++.  But although it is valid, C++ (opposed to C) encourages explicitness in your casting:

```
auto i = static_cast<int>(7.0);
```

(Oh, and use the type safe streams instead of the error-prone printf:

```
std::cout << i << "\n";
```

Comment: Good answer. I'd mention the type safety improvement by using static_cast.

Comment: It is valid in C++ but –unless I am mistaken – not valid in C.

Comment: @MartinR, you are correct. It is not valid in C. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39888307/434551).

Comment: @MartinR: thanks.  Indeed - I know little of C.  Corrected