# C programing: pointer to a function

Tags: c

I'm new in `C` programming. Could you read and explain the purpose of below code:

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)();
void func_call (int addr)
{
    func_ptr func;
    func = (func_ptr)(addr);
    func();
}
```

I don't understand what `func = (func_ptr)(addr);` do and the purpose of `func();`
Thanks.

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558837/what-exactly-is-a-type-cast-in-c-c).

Comment: If you are new to C, don't jump into the deep end before getting comfortable in the shallows. Get a good book on C, and learn it in a structured manner.

Comment: The code you don't understand is flawed and faulty. You can not put a pointer in an `int` variable. Well you *can* but it's not correct and if the `sizeof(int)` is smaller than `sizeof(func_ptr)` you will have very big troubles on your hand. It is not a good example to learn from, and you should throw it away.

Comment: Are you using 32bit machine? Converting int to pointer is unlikely what you want in 64bit machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first line

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)();
```

declare `func ptr` as an alias of type `void (*)()`. Now `func_ptr` can be used to declare a function pointer in the program. Therefore

```
func_ptr func;
```

declares `func` as a function pointer of type `void (*)()`. It is equivalent to

```
void (*func)();
```

Now this function pointer can point to a function and then can be used to call that function. I guess `addr` is used as an address of a function and then this address is casted to the type of `func_ptr` in the statement

```
func = (func_ptr)(addr);
```

`func()` is used to call that function.

Comment: @haccks: thank you. Your answer helps me understand the remaining :). You are correct: addr is used as an address of a function. Still, I wonder if it is ok to write like this: "func = func_ptr addr;". What does "()" mean?

Comment: @Phuong; `func = (func_ptr)(addr);` can be written as `func = (func_ptr)addr;` also.

Comment: @Phuong `()` surrounding a type name are used for so called "type casting". The value of a variable with type A is taken and interpreted as if it was of type B.

Comment: *Still, I wonder if it is ok to write like this: "func = func_ptr addr"*; No it is not.  `(func_ptr)` in the statement `func = (func_ptr)(addr);` is used for typecast.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. You have `func_ptr` which defines a pointer to function `void [name] ()`.
Your function `func_call (int addr)` creates variable `func` and assign to argument `addr` which casted to `func_ptr`. Then it calls by `func()`.

How it's says in comments - it's not correct. You will have very big troubles.