# What does (char*) mean in c?

Tags: c, pointers

What does `char*ptr=(char*)&i;`exactly do in the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
  int i=32;
  char*ptr=(char*)&i;
  printf("%d",*ptr);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Google search "cast in C".

Comment: Read the book. This is called cast operator and you are doing a casting.

Comment: [Type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7558837/335858)

Comment: it means you need to [read some book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/995714)

Answer (score 4):

```
char* ptr=(char*)&i;
```

`i` is of type `int`. So you are trying to cast address of `i` as a character pointer and assign it to a local variable called `ptr`. This way each byte stored in `i` can be read. Read more on pointers to understand in detail.