# What is this syntax? (parenthesis around variable type in C)

Tags: c

I understand what this code produce but I don't know what kind of syntax (or function) it is.

### code

```
void main()
{
    float af;
    int a = 75;
    int cov = 100;

    af = a/cov;
    printf("af: %f\n", af);
    af = (float) a/(float) cov;
    printf("af: %f\n", af);
}
```

### output

```
af: 0.000000
af: 0.750000
```

Without the `(float)` in front of the two `int` variables, it would have done the division between integers (thus returning 0.0) and then converted it to `float`, while with the `(float)` it seems to temporarly convert `a` and `cov` to float and than perform the division.

What is this `(type)` form?

Comment: It is exactly the way you described. How else does this work? ;-)

Comment: first convert to float and than divide -> 0.75

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question... a cast is there to enforce an explicit type conversion. So what's the question here?

Comment: When at least one of the operands of the division operator is a `float`, the result will be a `float`

Comment: That is a typecast. More info here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm

Comment: The term you need is 'type casting', in this case, explicit type casting. There's lots of info on SO and other places about how it works.

Comment: It's a cast. Personally I prefer `1.0f * a / cov`.

Comment: It's worth noting that casting is a unary prefix operator, and therefore has very high precedence (i.e., it is applied before almost all other operator). P.S. IMO it also makes it weird to leave a gap between the cast and the variable, to me it would be like seeing `++ a`.

Comment: @JamesSnook "before any other operator" -> "before most other operators". E.g. member access `.` and `->` are higher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is a type cast in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558837/what-exactly-is-a-type-cast-in-c-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a *typecast*, or *cast* for short. The syntax is:

```
(type) expression
```

It does exactly what you already inferred: it evaluates to the value of `expression`, converted to the given `type`.

Answer (score 0):

Type casting is a way to convert a variable from one data type to another data type.

```
(type_name) expression
```

Another way to do this is

```
float af;
int a = 75;
float cov = 100.0;

af = a/cov;
printf("af: %f\n", af);
```

The result would be a float.

Answer (score -1):

This is **typecasting**. Putting a type in parentheses before an expressions converts the expression to that type. For example,

```c
(int) 1.0; // gives 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
af = a/cov;
```

Integer division 75 / 100 = 0
this means in float -> 0.0

```
af = (float) a/(float) cov;
```

typcast 75 to float -> 75.0
typcast 100 to flat  -> 100.0
  float division 75.0 / 100.0 -> 0.75