# Parentheses around structure variable with asterisk operator

Tags: c

Consider the if statement:
`if (((DbSignal*) ev->newVal.buff)->sig)`

Where `DbSignal` is a structure.

Why is DbSignal within brackets and what is the asterisk operator doing in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `(DbSignal*)` is a typecast.  It converts one type to another.

In this case, the operand of the cast is `ev->newVal.buff` which presumably is a pointer to a character buffer.  This pointer is converted to a pointer to `DbSignal` via the cast.  The result is then dereferenced and the `sig` member is accessed.

Comment: For clarification, the ```newVal``` pointer within the structure that ```ev``` points to is having the buffer replaced with ```DbSignal``` and then ```newVal``` is being dereferenced to retrieve the ```sig``` value from ```DbSignal```?

Comment: @IllyaKara It's not being replaced but reinterpreted as a different type.  So the bytes that `newVal` points to are now being treated as if they are a `DbSignal`.

Answer (score 2):

It is the cast: `ev->newVal.buff` is casted to pointer to `DbSignal`. Then this pointer is being dereferenced (`sig` member accessed)

What is the type cast: [What exactly is a type cast in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558837/what-exactly-is-a-type-cast-in-c-c)

Answer (score 0):

We have `ev` which is a pointer in this case.
it points to a struct containing the variable `newVal` which contains a `buff` pointer.

So we have `ev->newVal.buff`

Here buff is either a `char*` or `void*` (a series of bytes, but apparently has some layout). Meaning that the memory it points to could potentially be interpreted in different ways.

By your example, we know that `buff` has a certain layout, corresponding to the `DbSignal` struct.

So in order to access `->sig` we have to cast this `.buff` to `DbSignal`, basically telling that we want to interpret that memory region with the layout described by `DbSignal`.

Hope this gives some context.